# Login com JAAS + Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsf, hibernate

Fiz os procedimentos de configuração do JAAS no meu projeto JSF,quando tento acessar mostra a informação que usuário e senha não confere, porém já criei a tabela de usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

context.xml

```
<Context path="/FastChoice">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
     driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastchoice" 
     connectionName="root" connectionPassword="admin" 
     userTable="usuario" userNameCol="nome_usuario" 
     userCredCol="senha"  userRoleTable="permissao_usuario"
     roleNameCol="nome_permissao"/>
```

Classe SegurancaBean como o método logar

```
public class SegurancaBean {

private String usuario;
private String senha;

public String logar() {
  try {
    this.getRequest().login(this.usuario, this.senha);
    return "Home?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        FacesUtil.adicionarMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                FacesUtil.getMensagemI18n("username_password_does_not_match"));
        return null;
    }
}

public String sair() throws ServletException {
    this.getRequest().logout();
    return "Login?faces-redirect=true";
}


private HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}
```

}

Login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>#{msg.login}</title>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="width: 240px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 150px">
            <h1>#{msg.login}</h1>

            <h:form id="frm">

                <h:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" 
                    styleClass="form-messages" errorClass="error"/>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="form-grid" style="padding: 10px"
                        columnClasses="label, campo" id="panel">

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.username}"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{segurancaBean.usuario}" size="20"/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}"/>
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{segurancaBean.senha}" size="20"/>

                    <h:panelGroup/>
                    <h:commandButton value="#{msg.login}" action="#{segurancaBean.logar}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

Comment: A abordagem que uso é criar minha propria classe de Realm usando JPA. De qualquer forma eu sugiro uma abordagem em que você teste primeiro o JASS com um servlet simples e só depois integre com o Faces.

Comment: Ok, irei procurar artigos sobre JPA, pois nunca usei.

Comment: David Filipe, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Agora, na prática tenha em mente que no Java EE, os containeres são responsáveis por fornecer segurança de aplicativos. Um container basicamente provê dois tipos de segurança: declarativa e programática.

Pessoalmente, prefiro implementar segurança usando o tipo de segurança declarativa porque como as informações do descritor de implementação (web.xml; jboss-web.xml; standalone.xml; domain.xml) são contidos/definidos em um arquivo externo, ele pode ser alterado sem a necessidade de modificar o código-fonte. E isso é um benefício e reduz a manutenção e refatoramento dos código-fonte.

Para entender o tipo de segurança declarativa usando

[image: Tipo de segurança: declarativa]
Fonte: [[Michal Cmil et al -  2014](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly), 309 p.]

E considere o seguinte:

> O formulário de login deve conter campos para inserir um nome de usuário e senha. Esses campos devem ser nomeados j_username e j_password, respectivamente. O formulário de autenticação deve postar esses valores no nome lógico j_security_check.
>
> Todos esses nomes que começam com j_ são padronizados pela especificação Java Servlet - precisamos apenas seguir a convenção para permitir que os mecanismos automáticos funcionem.[[Michal Cmil et al -  2014](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly), 310 p.]

Acredito que no seu caso, altere o seu formulário conforme a seguir:

```
<h:form id="frm" method="post" action="j_security_check" >
    <h:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" 
        styleClass="form-messages" errorClass="error" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="form-grid" style="padding: 10px"
            columnClasses="label, campo" id="panel">

        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.username}"/>
        <h:inputText name="j_username" value="#{segurancaBean.usuario}" size="20"/>

        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}"/>
        <h:inputSecret name="j_password" value="#{segurancaBean.senha}" size="20"/>

        <h:panelGroup/>
        <h:commandButton value="#{msg.login}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[Juneau, Josh -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Java EE 7 Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430244259)**: A problem-Solution Approach – Proven Solutions for Java Enterprise Edition 7 Developement</sub> 
<sub>[Gonçalves, Antonio -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Beginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O)** (Expert Voice in Java)</sub>
<sub>[JSR 196 - JASPIC], **[JSR 196 - JASPIC](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=196)**: JavaTM Authentication Service Provider Interface for Containers</sub>
<sub>[Anjana Mankale -  2013], Copyright © 2013 Packt Publishing, **[Spring Security 3.x Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/spring-security-3x-cookbook)**: Over 60 recipes to help you successfully safeguard your web applications with Spring Security.</sub>
<sub>[Michal Cmil et al -  2014], Copyright © 2014 Packt Publishing, **[Java EE 7 Development with WildFly](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly)**: Leverage the power of the WildFly application server from JBoss to develop modern Java EE 7 applications.</sub>