# Controle de autenticação em Java Web

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, tomcat

Boa noite, estou fazendo um projeto usando *JSF, Hibernate e Tomcat* e um dos requisitos é:

**X RF 01**.    O sistema deve utilizar senhas de acesso para o controle seguro da aplicação.

O que eu poderia usar nesse controle? Tentei o **JAAS** porém não consegui fazer funcionar, até criei uma perguntar aqui e ninguém conseguiu me responder, também encontrei pouquíssimo assunto para estudar mais sobre esse tipo de autenticação. Tem mais algum?

Comment: Fala David, tudo certo? Já deu uma olhada no Shiro? Segue o link: http://shiro.apache.org/

Comment: Grande Weslley, ainda não tinha visto nada sobre o Shiro, irei pesquisar sobre ele, principalmente em português já que meu inglês é péssimo kk, obrigado.

Comment: Se for pra um trabalho escolar, você não poderia implementar a sua própria solução para essa autenticação?

Comment: É um projeto web da faculdade, no requisito tem controle seguro da aplicação, creio eu que pode ser usado qualquer tipo de ferramenta. Como eu falei, estou tentando usa JAAS, fiz tudo certo, porém quando tento logar aparece a mensagem de login ou senha incorreta. Tá aqui nessa pergunta.

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96743/login-com-jaas-tomcat?noredirect=1#comment196253_96743

Comment: David Filipe, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa ao apache shiro é o spring-security, um projeto bem maduro, com sua ultima release na versão 4.0.4. Seguem dois links que podem te ajudar:

1- http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/ (Documentação Oficial) 
2- http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-spring-security/29402